# Package is not showing up in the dart packages folder even though it is installed

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-graphql

I have been having issues with installing this package https://pub.dev/packages/graphql_flutter/install one of it's dependencies is this graphql package https://pub.dev/packages/graphql. When i do pub get it installs en shows everything expect for the graphql package in the dart packages folders. I have tried to install the graphql package separately but the package still doesnt show up than. And the import still gives the error "Target of URI doesn't exist: 'package:graphql/client.dart'." But it does show up in flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org so i dont understand why it doesnt show in my project. I have tried using flutter clean, flutter clean pub cache and androidstudio's invalidate caches/restart function to no avail. I have also tried restarting android studio and my pc multiple times. I have also tried it with androidstudio run as admin.

This is my pubspec.yaml
[image: This is my pubspec.yaml file]

this is part of my Dart packages folder as you can see it does not show 
[image]

 
 And this is the pub.dartlang.org folder on my pc
[image]

Answer (score 1):

It ended up getting randomly fixed after 3 days. I just started android studio up and tried it again and suddenly it worked. No idea what fixed it in the end

Answer (score 1):

**Quick Solution**

1. Run the command **flutter pub cache repair**
2. Run the **flutter pub get** and that's it

Answer (score 0):

Seen this issue a few times.  Open Task manager in windows and check for adb.exe.  There should be one copy running.  I had 2 copies so removed 1 and restarted the other.

right-click --> end task for both.

All ok then.

Answer (score 0):

Reloading VS code worked for me..

Reloading can be done ---> **Command + R** for Mac.